# What is the to on the ruby delegate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

An application that I am managing has this code in the users model

```
delegate :can?, :cannot?, :to => :ability
```

I know that delegate can be a shortcut for associations but I dont understand the `:to => :ability`

I am assuming that its a shortcut for the ability.rb for cancan but not 100% sure

Comment: do you have a "def ability" in the user model ?

Answer (score 4):

That syntax boils down to the following:

```
delegate(:can?, :cannot?, {:to => :ability})
```

From the [`delegate` docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate), the `:to` option defines the target object to delegate to.  (CanCan probably defines an `ability` instance method wherever you're calling this)